# QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qt4

What could be cause of `QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError` when using `QTcpSocket`?

---

**CODE**

I'm getting this error code with the following code:

```
this->connect(socket, SIGNAL(socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), SLOT(handleSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
...
void MyClass::handleSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
{
    qDebug() << error;
}
```

---

**MORE INFO**

The QTcpSocket is trying to connect to some remote host. And it fails with mentioned error code.

Comment: You should add some information on how you are using it, otherwise the only obvious answer is *"an unidentified error"*.

Comment: I've added some information to the question. Don't know what else could I add.

Comment: Print the errorString() too. That would probably help.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the code, you'll see that this error means exactly what it says: "something bad happened and I don't know why". There had to be exceptions, of course:

- The socket is not connected to a server and you try to write to it (`src/network/socket/qabstractsocket.cpp` on line 2025)
- An SSL error occurred (`src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl.cpp` in a lot of places)

In both situations the errorString is set to an appropriate message.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you called the `error()` function when there is no error.

Comment: I've just checked your idea against my code. No, this error code is emitted with the QAbstractSocket::error signal. I've edited the question to reflect this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for AbstractSocketError in the Qt sources gives quite some hits. Maybe fire up a debugger and look into the backtrace when you get the error() signal. Possibly an exotic error condition occured in the underlying socket engine (which is a Qt internal class).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no opportunity to debug the code since it is a windows service being run on a remote server, and described behavior doesn't reproduce all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Does remote host require ssl connection? It may be problem if your Qt copy can't load libssl. I had same problem (UnkownSocketError) when Qt couldn't find libssl

Comment: No, the connection is pure TCP. Thanks for answer anyway.