# QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError provides errorString of "UnknownError"

Tags: qt, sockets, enums, qtcpsocket, qabstractsocket

I am unable to get any further information regarding this error:

```
QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError
```

The QT [QAbstractSocket::SocketError](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketError-enum) provides only a basic explaination that some error has occured

> An unidentified error occurred.
>
> enum value = -1

Calling QTcpSocket::errorString() provides this:

```
"Unknown error"
```

There is [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885605/qabstractsocketunknownsocketerror) regarding this here on SO but provides no real solution to solving the issue (and what was suggested I have done)

I have absoltely no idea how to further progress with this error

*p.s. I looked for some stacktrace/backtrace option, didn't find anything - if there is, please leave a comment*

**UPDATE**

**Code:**

//Server

```
//...
if (tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress().AnyIPv4, 5000)) {
    qDebug() << "tcpserver started on port : 5000";
}
else{
    qDebug() << "tcpserver failed to start";
}
//...
```

//Client

```
//...
tcp_con = new QTcpSocket(new QObject());
tcp_con->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 5000);

switch (tcp_con->error()) {
    //...
    case QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError:
    qDebug() << "tcp error UnknownSocketError closed : " << tcp_con->errorString();
    return;
    //...
}
```

**Client debug output:**

```
tcp error UnknownSocketError closed :  "Unknown error"
```

Any advice?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or, at the very least, some relevant code.

Comment: try telnet as client to connect to your tcp server

Comment: @Redanium thanks, I shall try it. But if it succeeds, it still proves that something in the client in not functioning properly. There are examples of fortune client and server provided by Qt. I took the core parts of connectToHost, etc. non of the QNetworkConfigurations, etc. I implemented this and still does not work, but their provided example does. I have to investigate this further

Comment: @KGCybeX I tried your code in a simple example and the output is similar to yours.If you look at the fortune examples which are two **asynchronous** and **synchronous**, you are implementing the **client** in a synchronous way without the use of `bool QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected(int msecs = 30000)` and `UnknownSocketError` you can get it even if the connection is successful.So either use `bool QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected(int msecs = 30000)` for synchronous or use `[signal] void QAbstractSocket::connected()` (signal/slot mechanism) for asynchronous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QTcpSocket connecting results in UnknownSocketError with errorString "UnknownError"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042579/qtcpsocket-connecting-results-in-unknownsocketerror-with-errorstring-unknownerr)