# QTcpSocket connecting results in UnknownSocketError with errorString "UnknownError"

Tags: qt, sockets, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver, qabstractsocket

**Problem**

I am unable to get any further information regarding this error:

```
QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError
```

The QT [QAbstractSocket::SocketError](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketError-enum) provides only a basic explanation that some error has occurred

> An unidentified error occurred.
>
> enum value = -1

Calling QTcpSocket::errorString() provides this:

```
"Unknown error"
```

There is [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885605/qabstractsocketunknownsocketerror) regarding this here on SO but provides no real solution to solving the issue (and what was suggested I have done)

I have absoltely no idea how to further progress with this error, since each time my client attempts to connect (after calling [connectToHost()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connectToHost)) I get this error.

**Code:**

//Server

```
//...
if (tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress().AnyIPv4, 5000)) {
    qDebug() << "tcpserver started on port : 5000";
}
else{
    qDebug() << "tcpserver failed to start";
}
//...
```

I also went on to explicitly set the server ip to localhost and port 5000, but without success.

//Client

```
//...
tcp_con = new QTcpSocket(new QObject());
tcp_con->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 5000);

switch (tcp_con->error()) {
    //...
    case QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError:
    qDebug() << "tcp error UnknownSocketError closed : " << tcp_con->errorString();
    return;
    //...
}
```

**Client debug output:**

```
tcp error UnknownSocketError closed :  "Unknown error"
```

Any advice?

*p.s. I looked for some stacktrace/backtrace option, didn't find anything - if there is, please leave a comment*

Comment: There are different errors in programming, and some of them has nothing known about the cause. Some errors may be found only by checking the code logic. Also you can put here a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we will try to help

Comment: Also the part `new QTcpSocket(new QObject());` looks strange

Comment: @VladimirBershov thanks for the suggestion. I have changed that to `new QTcpSocket(this)` where `this` is a `QDialog`. And `QDialog` indirectly inherits `QObject`.

Comment: @VladimirBershov this change resulted in no difference in outcome. This error persists p.s. I too thought this might be a problem but seems like it wasn't

Comment: what about a MCVE, and what about [QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected) for the `tcp_con` variable

Comment: @VladimirBershov indeed, it makes little sense to check `error()` right after `connectToHost()` when nothing has happend yet.
I would recommend to connect to the `error()` signal instead and do the error handling in there.

Comment: @KevinKrammer thank you for this suggestion, it makes much more sense. I shall implement this too

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong to check an error immediately after the `connectToHost()`, because this is not a complete action, and the `errorString()` will always return "Unknown error". You have to call the [QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected) method like this:

```
tcp_con->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 5000);
if (tcp_con->waitForConnected(1000))
    qDebug("Connected!");
```

Or you can don't call the `waitForConnected()` and asynchronously wait while the signal [connected()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connected) will be emitted:

```
connect(tcp_con, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
        this, SLOT(onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(tcp_con, SIGNAL(connected()),
        this, SLOT(onConnect()));
//...
void MyClass::onConnect()
{
    qDebug() << "Connected!";
}

void MyClass::onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)
{  
    QTcpSocket* sock = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    qDebug() << "Socket error:" << sock->errorString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, i had a hunch that it might be something like this, i will implement it and return with an answer